# How do you add a calculated column to a pandas dataframe using set-based logic?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to python (background in T-SQL and R) and looking for a set-based method for adding a calculated column to a Pandas Dataframe. R and T-SQL have simple implementations for this concept, but I've yet to find a solution to this in Python.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24976274/adding-a-calculated-column-to-pandas-dataframe) is an iterative approach to what I'm looking for. I'm looking for something more set-based, and have yet to find a solution.

Here is an example from R:

```
# New column that shows if the value in column A is greater than the value in column B

myDataFrame$CalculatedColumn = ifelse(myDataFrame$columnA > myDataFrame$columnB,TRUE,FALSE)
```

This statement will add a new calculated column without requiring row-by-row evaluation code.

Does Python (or any Python packages) support a concept like this? Or is the most practical solution way to call iterrows() in a for loop?

Let me know if any clarifications are needed - and thanks for the help!

Comment: a sample of before and after data would be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply be able to do a direct comparison.

```
df['C'] = df.A > df.B
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander that looks very simple to implement. If you don't mind me asking, can you apply multiple conditional statements like this? For example, could you do something like A > B and B !=2 ?

Comment: `df['C'] = (df.A > df.B) & (df.B != 2)`.  For logical OR, use `|`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for that:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(10,2)), columns = ["A", "B"])
df
Out[46]: 
   A  B
0  2  8
1  9  5
2  4  4
3  6  0
4  5  5
5  0  8
6  7  9
7  6  3
8  0  9
9  0  9
```

---

```
df["C"] = np.where(df["A"] > df["B"], True, False)
df
Out[48]: 
   A  B      C
0  2  8  False
1  9  5   True
2  4  4  False
3  6  0   True
4  5  5  False
5  0  8  False
6  7  9  False
7  6  3   True
8  0  9  False
9  0  9  False
```

Comment: Why bring `np.where` into it?  Isn't this basically the same as `df["C"] = df["A"] > df["B"]`?

Comment: @DSM OP's example from R has the option to return values other than True and False so I tried to provide something similar to that one. I don't know if it's possible without using `np.where`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways to do this in Pandas.  If indeed there are only 2 values (True or False) then you might be best off just splitting it into two lines like so:

```
df['newCol'] = False
df.loc[df['colA'] > df['colB'],'newCol'] = True
```

Typically, I try any way I can to not do iterrows.  It's very slow.

Hope that helps.

Comment: For the problem I'm trying to solve today I can probably make that work. I'll give it a shot and mark the question as answered afterwards. Out of curiosity, if there are multiple values (beyond True/False in my question) is there a different approach you'd take? Many thanks!

Comment: I typically use the above approach wherever I'd use an if statement in sql.  When it gets to something where you would use a case statement (comparing multiple columns, not just the true/false of an if) it can get a little bit hairy.  Either I'll have a line of code per "case" or I'll write some kind of function.  I'd love to hear if there is a better way myself...